# Redirect to a specific path after session timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am working on ruby on rails, and using devise for authentication. By enabling `:timeoutable` session is timing out and redirecting to `root_path` after certain time. But I need to redirect to a different path like `new_session_path`. Is there any devise call back function for timeout redirect or some configuration for redirect path.

Please anyone help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `after_sign_out_path_for` method. Add this method in your `ApplicationController` as a `private` method:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  root_path
end
```

Take a look at [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out) for details.

Comment: I tried that, it is working when we explicitly sign out, but not working in the case of automatic session timeout and refresh the page.

Comment: when you refresh the page, session is still there, its not expired.